# Is it possible to replace the name at the end of the R.string. call with a variable

Tags: java, android

Hie sorry, noob here so dont really know termology. What i want to do is replace the end of a command like this

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rr)).setText(R.string.Constitution);
```

to something more dynamic, substituting the word Constitution, which is a reference to a string in the strings.xml resource, with a variable. This is the way i thought would work, but it isant

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String textFromSpinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (textFromSpinner.contains(" ")){
        textFromSpinner = textFromSpinner.replaceAll(" ", "_");
    }

    String valueToGet = "R.string" + textFromSpinner;

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rr)).setText(valueToGet);

}
```

that refused, I also tried a number of variations that were rejected immediately by Android Studio which showed me red lines.

Please help, and also, please be kind in as i am still learning how to code so i am not knowlegebale

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: R.string.Constitution generates unique integer id not  string

Comment: thank you, that just solved a lot of problems on its own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int stringId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(textFromSpinner, "string", context.getPackageName());
```

With this line you can get the id of your desired string resource. Then you can pass it to your `TextView`:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rr)).setText(stringId);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried your method, the IDE couldnt resolve context... did more reading, i found somewhere where it said i should create a class called context, or something, im sorry, im new to programming so some simple things may be dificult to me, but i do read up on it, thanks so much, the matter has been resolved tho thanks to everyone who replied. I read up on ProtossShuttle reply and worked from there, my final code is at the bottom. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can call `getResource().getIdentifier()` method to retrieve a resource by its name at runtime. Check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked and i read on it using your link. Much appriciated

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem. And could you accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello %1$s</string>
```

Replace @runtime

```
String str = "World";
str = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world), str );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its much appreciated. I followed ProtossShuttle's reply and read on it more and everything worked. thanks a lot for your input

Answer (score 0):

```
 int searchId = getResources().getIdentifier(textFromSpinner, "string", this.getPackageName());
    if (searchId != 0){
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rr)).setText(searchId);
    } else {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rr)).setText(R.string.Please_Select_Option);
    }
```